# NSInternalInconsistencyException when collapsing section of rows from UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I attempt to delete rows to simulate collapsing a section in my UITableView, I get the following error message:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

I'm using this method to delete the rows, where the caller is the header view of the section, and its tag is its section:

```
- (IBAction)toggleExpand:(id)sender
{
int section = [sender tag];

if (expandedArray[section]) {
    expandedArray[section] = NO;
    NSMutableArray *rowsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        [rowsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }
    [mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:rowsToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }
}
```

It seems like the issue is that I'm not updating my data source after deleting the rows, but I am trying to do that with my method numberOfRowsInSection:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (expandedArray[section]) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

expandedArray is an array of bools, which are all intiated as YES, because all sections are by defualt expanded.

EDIT: I added some debug messages, and received the following.

```
Asking number of rows....
Section 1 is expanded.
Asking number of rows....
Section 0 is expanded.
header section: 0
header section: 1
toggleExpand tag reads: 0
Asking number of rows....
Section 0 is expanded.
Asking number of rows....
Section 1 is not expanded.
```

What's troubling me is that it thinks Section 1 is collapsed when it should be Section 0.

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything right. The only thing that looks suspicious is the calculation of `section` inside the `toggleExpand:` method: are you certain that the tag corresponds to a valid section? One way to find out is to replace the call of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` with refreshing the data "wholesale" for the entire table, and seeing if the model is changed correctly.

Comment: Could you clarify that last point a little? Are you saying I should delete the data from the model without removing the rows?

Comment: "Could you clarify that last point a little?" The call of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` deletes rows "nicely", with animation etc. While this is the right way of doing it, you can also tell your table to refresh all data. It is not visually pleasant, but it will show you the state of your table model. Replace the call with `[tableView reloadData]` and see what section gets collapsed. "What's troubling me is that it thinks Section 1 is collapsed when it should be Section 0." It sounds like the tag that is coming in is incorrect: most likely you have an "off-by-one" error somewhere.